# Early triggering and chained aggregations in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is it possible to compose/chain together multiple aggregations with different windowing and triggering in Apache Beam.

**Example:**

I have an input of `PCollection<KV<String, Long>>`, and I need to compute 2 sums: 1 min fixed windows, and 1 hour sliding windows every 1 min, and I want to get speculative results every minute.

*Trigger:*

```
Trigger trigger =
    Repeatedly.forever(
            AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                // Speculative every ONE_MINUTE
                .plusDelayOf(ONE_MINUTE))
        // final result past watermark
        .orFinally(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow());
```

Having an input: `PCollection<KV<String, Long>> input` I can do it with 2 aggregations:

```
PCollection<KV<String, Long>> oneMinSum = input
    .apply(Window.into(1 min).triggering(trigger))
    .apply(Sum.longsPerKey())
```

and

```
PCollection<KV<String, Long>> slidingSum = input
    .apply(Window.into(1 hour sliding 1 min).triggering(trigger))
    .apply(Sum.longsPerKey())
```

But in this case second aggregation will be doing sums over exactly the same data that was already used in one-min sums, if I can use `oneMinSum` as an input to sliding aggregation, I would save a ton of CPU, but this doesn't work, second aggregation computes sum over early triggered panes and final pane, double counting and producing incorrect sliding sum.

Full test case is here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2920e870a02abcbec51e10c3fd293236

**Output**

```
key=a value=1
    window=[2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z..2017-01-01T00:10:00.000Z)
    pane=PaneInfo{isFirst=true, timing=EARLY, index=0}
key=a value=5
    window=[2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z..2017-01-01T00:10:00.000Z)
    pane=PaneInfo{timing=EARLY, index=1}
key=a value=7
    window=[2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z..2017-01-01T00:10:00.000Z)
    pane=PaneInfo{isLast=true, timing=ON_TIME, index=2, onTimeIndex=0}
```

All examples that I've seen assumes that `Window.into` applied to `PCollection` only once, and after aggregates computed, results go to some storage (e.g. BigQuery, etc...), I've never seen any example of "chaining" aggregations and changing windowing multiple times.

Is it correct use case for Beam programming model? Or Beam programming model assumes that `Window.into(...).triggering(...)` will be specified only once?

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: to address the issue, use `discardingFiredPanes` in the first aggregation.

The trigger you specified is different from what you think.
`AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(ONE_MINUTE))`
triggers 1 min after the first element in the pane, but because you also use `accumulatingFiredPanes()` and `Repeatedly.forever(...)`, the trigger will fire

(i) 1 min after the first element for the first time

(ii) every time when there's a new element coming after (i) is satisfied

For your test case, I annotated what happens to `oneMinSum`

```
.advanceWatermarkTo(t0)
.addElements(KV.of("a", 1))
.advanceProcessingTime(TWO_MINUTES) // emit (a, 1) because of (i)
.addElements(KV.of("a", 1))
.advanceProcessingTime(TWO_MINUTES) // emit (a, 2) because of (ii)
.advanceWatermarkTo(t1)             // emit another (a, 2) past watermark
.addElements(KV.of("a", 1))
.advanceProcessingTime(TWO_MINUTES) // emit (a, 1) because of (i)
.advanceWatermarkToInfinity();      // emit another (a, 1) past watermark
```

The double emission of `(a, 2)` and `(a, 1)` is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760273/apache-beam-number-of-times-a-pane-is-fired-with-early-triggers).

For `onHourSums`, you get

- `key=a value=1` because of early trigger
- `key=a value=5 (1+2+2)` because of early trigger
- `key=a value=7 (1+2+2+1+1)` because of window closing