# Apache Beam number of times a pane is fired with early triggers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In a streaming beam pipeline, a trigger is set to be

```
Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardHours(1)))
              .triggering(AfterWatermark
                            .pastEndOfWindow()
                            .withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime
                                    .pastFirstElementInPane()
                                    .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(15))))
              .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardHours(1))
              .accumulatingFiredPanes())
```

1. If there's no new data between the early firing (15 minutes after the first element of the current window) and the watermark, will there be another firing at the end of the watermark?
2. If yes, under the same scenario, will there be another firing at the end of the watermark if `accumulatingFiredPanes` is changed to `discardingFiredPanes`?

Comment: Paraphrasing (1), when using `accumulatingFiredPanes`, will beam fire the exact same pane that was early fired again after watermark?

Comment: Adding a 3, will the answer to the previous questions change if `.withOnTimeBehavior(Window.OnTimeBehavior.FIRE_IF_NON_EMPTY)` is specified? This API is annotated as `@Experimental`. I'm not sure if it takes any real effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. There should always be a firing when the watermark passes the end of the window. The early firing panes will be marked as early, and the watermark pane will be marked as on time.
2. Yes, currently we always guarantee an on_time pane, which means there will be a firing at the end of the watermark.

Comment: for point 2, there will be a fire even when the firing pane is empty. For an empty pane, what will the downstream `PCollection` get for such an empty pane (say the transformation is some `Combine` and `withoutDefaults` configured)?

Answer (score 1):

For #2, you can set the `Window.ClosingBehavior` as second parameter to `withAllowedLateness`. There are two variants:

- FIRE_ALWAYS
- FIRE_IF_NON_EMPTY

See https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/Window.ClosingBehavior.html