# Apache Beam / Java / Dataflow - Session window with early trigger not firing the "on-time" pane when when the watermark hits

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Using apache beam 2.31 over Dataflow using java. 
**Window**:

```
Window.<KV<String, HeartBeat>>into(Sessions.withGapDuration(
                        Duration.standardMinutes(30)))
                .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
                        .withEarlyFirings(
                                AfterProcessingTime
                                        .pastFirstElementInPane().plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(20))
                        )
                ))
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(0))
                .accumulatingFiredPanes();
```

After applying the window theres a groupby and then the function that process the panes:

```
  boolean isFinished = context.pane().getTiming() != PaneInfo.Timing.EARLY;
```

**Expected behavior**: That an `on-time` pane will be fired as well as the early once.
As written here:
[Apache Beam number of times a pane is fired with early triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760273/apache-beam-number-of-times-a-pane-is-fired-with-early-triggers) the "on-time" have to fired

**Actual behavior**: `isFinished` always stays false and `on-time` never fires when using dataflow.

**Solutions that didn't work**:

1. Adding allowed lateness, and then marking `LATE` panes as finished - worked partially
2. Using `Window.ClosingBehavior.FIRE_ALWAYS` and `withOnTimeBehavior(Window.OnTimeBehavior.FIRE_ALWAYS)` - still had no `on-time` fire.

I wish to know how to solve this, as well why it works locally and not when deploying. Is it a dataflow problem? or wrong trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Found my bug - Problem was with timestamps of protobuff weren't processed right.